# Null to Zero Function in Access

Tags: null, zero

I am trying to do a query to summarize some monthly sales data.

Currently if there is no sales in a certain month then when I subsequently do a pivot chart it doesn't appear as month and therefore distorts my graph.

I have looked at earlier posts and seen the use of If and Null to overcome this but I have tried this in the SQL below and just keep getting a syntax error - can anyone help with what I am doing wrong below - have I put the 'If' in the wrong place? 
Thanks very much

TRANSFORM Sum(TBL_GM201415SHIPMENT.[Value 2014/15]) AS [SumOfValue 2014/15]
SELECT TBL_SUPPLIERINFORMATION.[Numeric Code]
FROM TBL_SUPPLIERINFORMATION INNER JOIN (tbl_PERIODS INNER JOIN TBL_GM201415SHIPMENT ON tbl_PERIODS.Period=TBL_GM201415SHIPMENT.[Handover FP]) ON TBL_SUPPLIERINFORMATION.[Numeric Code]=TBL_GM201415SHIPMENT.[Supplier Alpha Code]

****SELECT IIF(ISNULL([SumofValue 2014/15]), 0, [SumofValue2014/15]) FROM [TBL_GM201415SHIPMENT]****

GROUP BY TBL_SUPPLIERINFORMATION.[Numeric Code]
PIVOT tbl_PERIODS.Period;

Answer (score 0):

look at the `Nv` function:

> You can use the Nz function to return zero, a zero-length string ("
>   "), or another specified value when a Variant is Null. For example,
>   you can use this function to convert a Null value to another value and
>   prevent it from propagating through an expression.

[http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/nz-function-HA001228890.aspx][1]